# Loop over specific names on list in R

Tags: r, list, for-loop

This might be a rookie question but I have not found a solution to this apparently very simple problem
I have a problem on looping over a list that looks like this while making a exploratory factor analysis.

```
lista
    > $title [1] "Very Simple Structure"
    >        $map1 [1] 0.04220402
    >        $map2 [1] 0.06603451
    >        $map3 [1] 0.1058799
    >        $map4 [1] 0.1699387
    >        $map5 [1] 0.2758397
    >        $map6 [1] 0.4380119
    >        $map7 [1] 1
    >        $map8 [1] NA
    >        $cfit.11 [1] 0.8420674
    >        $cfit.12 [1] 0.6698345
    >        $cfit.13 [1] 0.4633054
    >        $cfit.14 [1] 0.4735214
    >        $cfit.15 [1] 0.4553064
    >        $cfit.16 [1] 0.3340032
    >        $cfit.17 [1] 0.3183872
    >        $cfit.18 [1] 0.2988131
    >        $cfit.21 [1] 0
    >        $cfit.22 [1] 0.8860225
    >        $cfit.23 [1] 0.7681796
    >        $cfit.24 [1] 0.7806282
    >        $cfit.25 [1] 0.7115525
    >        $cfit.26 [1] 0.5425901
    >        $cfit.27 [1] 0.5208224
    >        $cfit.28 [1] 0.5083072
    >        $vss.stats.dof1 [1] 20
    >        $vss.stats.dof2 [1] 13
    >        $vss.stats.dof3 [1] 7
    >        $vss.stats.dof4 [1] 2
    >        $vss.stats.dof5 [1] -2
    >        $vss.stats.dof6 [1] -5
    >        $vss.stats.dof7 [1] -7
    >        $vss.stats.dof8 [1] -8
    >        $vss.stats.chisq1 [1] 90.61919
    >        $vss.stats.chisq2 [1] 34.42475
    >        $vss.stats.chisq3 [1] 2.843969
    >        $vss.stats.chisq4 [1] 5.679727
    >        $vss.stats.chisq5 [1] 0.02348315
    >        $vss.stats.chisq6 [1] 1.39627e-10
    >        $vss.stats.chisq7 [1] 0
    >        $vss.stats.chisq8 [1] 0
    >        $vss.stats.prob1 [1] 5.77613e-11
    >        $vss.stats.prob2 [1] 0.001037037
    >        $vss.stats.prob3 [1] 0.8990514
    >        $vss.stats.prob4 [1] 0.05843364
```

When I try to make this loop over only the names of the list that are **vss.stats.prob"n"** (n is defined) I get back a display of null values

```
for(i in 1:n){   
print(lista$vss.stats.prob[[i]])  
}
```

If I make it like this I get back the proper value that is stored in the list as vss.stats.prob1 (1, 2, 3... n)

```
  print(lista$vss.stats.prob1)
```

I have tried to include this [i] any way possible and nothing seems to work on not returning a list of empty values.

I have tried to solve this by many methods and still can't find a solution, mind I'm not very familiar with R structures since I'm used to Stata programming.

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide a `dput` of the list?

Comment: try `for(i in paste0("vss.stats.prob", 1:n)) { print(lista[[i]] }`

Comment: One solution might be `grep`: `for(i in grep("vss.stats.prob", names(lista))){ `.